# Not able to get logged in user's username on remote machine in selenium grid setup

Tags: python, selenium-grid

I need the logged user's username for performing one of the action.

I tried using below 2 approached for same :

1. using userprofile : 
   `os.path.join(os.path.expandvars('%userprofile%'))`
   If tried this on python console it gives correct output , but when tried on remote machine of selenium grid setup gives output as : `C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile`
2. using getpass module of python :
   using `getpass.getuser()` on python console it gives correct output , but when tried on remote machine of selenium grid setup gives output as : hostname of the system.

Not sure what exactly is happening when we run command on remote machine using selenium grid setup .

Comment: I was using jenkins as service on the machine on which was causing the issue. Was able to resolve issue when started using jenkins as war using command line.